# Update assemblys without deploy clickonce again

Tags: deployment, clickonce

There is one problem about our infra architecture. 
The sever is working on the ship. So If the application changed,
The only thing I can do is that sending a file has been changed and someone who on the ship have to change a manifest file and copy the file at the folder that clickonce application has been deploy.

and then users try to run a application, the application has to be updated automatically.

I want to know is that 
 - The application can be updated when I change a assembly and manifest file in the server?
 - How can I?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you publish the ClickOnce app, and then have someone copy it to the server manually, and then it will update everyone's machine?